# Let $M$ and $N$ be two normal subgroups of a group $G$. Show that there exists a monomorphism from the group $G/M\cap N$ to $ G/M\times G/N$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

Let $M$ and $N$ be two normal subgroups of a group $G$. Show that there exists a monomorphism from the group $G/M\cap N$ to $ G/M\times G/N$.

My solution goes like this:

> Let $G,M,N,M\cap N$ be infinite. (The finite cases follow similarly) Let $G=\{g_1,g_2,...\},M=\{m_1,m_2,...\},N=\{n_1,n_2,n_3,...\},M\cap N=P=\{m_1,...\}(\text{We consider $m_1=e$}.)$ Now, $G/(M\cap N=P)=G/P=\{Pg_1,...\},G/M=\{Mg_1,...\},G/N=\{Ng_1,Ng_2,...\}.$ So, $G/M\times G/N=\{(Mg_1,Ng_1),...\}$. If we consider $f:G/P\longrightarrow G/M\times G/N$, such that, $f(Pg_1)=(Mg_1,Ng_1)$. Now, we prove that $f$ is a homomorphism as $f(Pg_1Pg_2)=f(Pg_1g_2)=(Mg_1g_2,Ng_1g_2)=(Mg_1,Ng_1)(Mg_2,Ng_2)=f(Pg_1)f(Pg_2)$. Now, if $f(Pg_1)=f(Pg_2)=(Mg_1,Ng_1)=(Mg_2,N_2)$, then $Mg_1=Mg_2$ and $Ng_1=Ng_2$. Thus, $g_1g_2^{-1}\in M \text{and } N$ and $g_1g_2^{-1}\in M \cap N=P$ thus, $Pg_1g_2^{-1}=P$ , hence, $Pg_1=Pg_2$, which proves $f$ to injective. Thus, $f$ is a monomorphism.

Is the above proof correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

Comment: Omg, I can not imagine myself reading algebra exam papers.

Comment: @BobDobbs Nice one!

Comment: You need surjectivity. I didn't see that word.

Comment: Find the word game.

Comment: @BobDobbs Ohh...editing it

Comment: @BobDobbs Just a sec...monomorphism means injective homomorphism ,right? I am not proving them isomorphic ,so I didn't require it...

Comment: @BobDobbs you give kicks so frequently atleast I didn't start a jumble game. During my earlier days, I loved playing "think the word" game better known as crossword...

Comment: Oh... Sorry.  Good less work.

Comment: @BobDobbs Nothing so big to say sorry though 

Comment: Two quibbles: you don't prove the map $f$ is well-defined; and you imply by your notation that the groups are countable (or finite).

Comment: @ancientmathematician How to prove it be well-defined? Apart from it, is the proof otherwise correct?(if we consider the function to be well-defined by obviously proving it)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Actually, for the notation part, I used $\cdots $ for a safer side due to the problem you specified.

Comment: As noted in a comment to an answer, this is a case that *screams* for the use of the first isomorphism theorem. Just define $G \to G/M \times G/N$ as $g \mapsto (g M, g N)$, and note that the kernel is $M \cap N$. In particular, the first isomorphism theorem takes care once and for all to show that your map is well defined, so you do not need to go through the motions every time.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti You are a genius! How do you come out with such brilliant mappings so quickly? I couldn't even think about this. A layman's question:Is there any standard way to come up with such mappings?Like a general strategy for these kind of problems?

Comment: @Franklin, thanks, but no genius here - I have just taught the subject for ages - and then there was an earlier remark to this effect in another comment. Anyway, the rule of thumb is that every time you are given an isomorphism of the form $G/K \to H$, where $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, you should try and have it coming from a surjective homomorphism $G \to H$ with kernel $K$. In this case you have only a monomorphism, but of course it can be regarded as an isomorphism replacing the codomain with the image. And in your case the map $g \mapsto (g M, g N)$ is quite natural.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Good tip! Thank you so much 

Answer (score 1):

A simple and elegant solution for this would be:

Let $p_M\colon G\twoheadrightarrow G/M$ (with $\ker(p_M)=M$) and $p_N\colon G\twoheadrightarrow G/N$ (with $\ker(p_N)=N$) be the canonical projections, then the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms applied to their product $p_M\times p_N\colon G\times G\rightarrow G/M\times G/N$ gives you an injection:
$$G/(M\cap N)
=G/\ker(p_M\times p_N)
\cong\operatorname{img}(p_M\times p_N)
\hookrightarrow G/M\times G/N.$$
If we have $G=M\cdot N$, then $p_M\times p_N$ would be surjective, so this would even be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You missed one of $g_2$s in your Mathjax text.

This is my quick solution which will get a few points in exam, trusting that the theorem is true:

Define $f:G/M\cap N\rightarrow G/M\times G/N$ by $f([g])=([g],[g])$.

1. Is $f$ homo.?: $f([g_1g_2])=([g_1g_2],[g_1g_2])=([g_1],[g_1])([g_2],[g_2])=f(g_1)f(g_2)$. So, $f$ is homo.
2. Is $f$ injective?: Let $f([g])=([e],[e])$. Then $g\in M$ and $g\in N$. So, $g\in M\cap N$. That is $[g]=e\in G/M\cap N$. So, $f$ is inj.
3. Is $f$ surjective?: Let $([g_1],[g_2])\in G/M\times G/N.$ Then we check that $f([g_1g_2]=([g_1g_2],[g_1g_2])=$.... What was asked? It may not be surjective.

Hence, we constructed the required mono.

New edit: Teacher asked me to prove the well-definedness of $f$. It was obvious to me. But, since it is obvious, it is mind consfusing. Suppose $[g]=[g']$ in $G/M\cap N$ be two different coset representetives. Then $[gg'^{-1}]=e$ in $G/M\cap N$. So, $gg'^{-1}\in M\cap N$ and thus $gg'^{-1}\in M$ and $gg'^{-1}\in N$ which implies that $[g]=[g']$ in both $G/M$ and $G/N$. So, $f([g']=([g'],[g'])=([g],[g])=f([g])$ as it wanted to be shown.

Comment: frustration no iso.

Comment: I think you have missed the crucial step $0$. Is $f$ well-defined? (Your definition is in terms of coset representatives, so you must check that different representatives give the same value.) If I were marking tis out of $10$ there would  be $4$ points for getting this right. You can avoid this by using and quoting the Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: Sorry. For 0.th step.

Comment: @BobDobbs Is my solution correct? I know, I haven't proved the well-defined part. But assuming I proved it, then will my solution hold? Ofc, I have to prove the well-defineness. Any idea about how to prove it?

Comment: +1 was me. After all this is a race. For wasting funny time in schoool.

Comment: @BobDobbs Ohh! I didn't know it. So, it's correct. Thanks for verifying, but the real problem is to show the well-defineness. If we can do that, then I will just paste the proof before my original solution to make it completely correct. But dunno how to do it?